# How can we write this in math?

Tags: real-analysis

I am given a function $f: X \times Y \times Z \times \mathbb N \to [0, \infty)$.

There exists a $x \in X$  such that for any $y \in Y$ and any $\epsilon > 0$,
there exists $n_\epsilon$ such that for $n ≥ n_\epsilon$, irrespective of $z \in Z$, 
$$
f(x,y,z,n) \leq \epsilon
$$

(1. How can we write the above in math?)

2. Is it the same as or equivalent to
   $$
   \inf_{x\in X} \sup_{y \in Y} \limsup_n \sup_{z \in Z} f(x,y,z,n) = 0?
   $$
   Or equvalent to something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the same? No. Is it equivalent? I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by "same"?

Comment: What do you mean, by "write in maths"? $\exists x\in X \ \forall y\in Y\ \forall \epsilon >0\ \exists n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall n \geq n_\epsilon\forall z\in Z\ f(x,y,z,n)\ \leq \epsilon$

Comment: @ClementC: what you wrote is in math. I also wonder if the single equation I gave is equivalent to the original statement? Or something similar to the equation?

Comment: @Tim By 'the same' I mean being equal. For instance $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\in A\land x\in B$ are equivalent statements but they certainly aren't the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you consider $f(x,y,z,n)$ as a sequence $f_n(x,y,z)$ of functions, then your statement says that $f_n$ converges pointwise in $\{x\}\times Y$ and uniformly wrt $z$ to $0$. This can be expressed like so:
\begin{align*}
\exists x\in X:\forall y\in Y:\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0.
\end{align*}
Since this is true for each $y\in Y$ we have
\begin{align*}
\exists x\in X:\sup_{y\in Y}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0.
\end{align*}
Now, since you dont know anything about $x'\neq x$, you can weaken this expression by using the $\limsup$, since it exists even in the extended sense. Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\exists x\in X:\sup_{y\in Y}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)&=0 \\
\forall x\in X:\sup_{y\in Y}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)\geq0
\end{align*}
(note that $f\geq0$), which implies
\begin{align*}
\inf_{x\in X}\sup_{y\in Y}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0.
\end{align*}
So in this sense, (1) implies (2) (if you add absolute values).

For the converse, you need that $\inf_{x\in X}$ can be replaced by $\min_{x\in X}$. Then there is some $x\in X$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{y\in Y}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0.
\end{align*}
But then
\begin{align*}
\forall y\in Y:\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0.
\end{align*}
This implies
\begin{align*}
\forall y\in Y:\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)=0,
\end{align*}
i.e. for fixed $y\in Y$ and $\varepsilon>0$ we find an $N\in\mathbb N$ (depending on $\varepsilon$, $x$ and $y$) such that $\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)<\varepsilon$ for each $n\geq N$; in particular, $f(x,y,z,n)<\varepsilon$ for each $n\geq N$ and $z\in Z$. So this shows (2) implies (1).

Only $\inf_{x\in X}$ is not sufficient. Consider $X=\mathbb R$ and $f(x,y,z,n)=e^x$. Note that $\inf_{x\in X}$ can be replaced by $\min_{x\in X}$, if $X$ is a compact topological space and $g(x):=\sup_{y\in Y}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in Z}f(x,y,z,n)$ is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Thanks. I should add that $f$ is nonnegative. Are the two in my post the same/equivalent?

Comment: Why do you treat $y$ different than $z$?

Comment: @mvw: From the statement, I guess $n_\epsilon$ may depend on $y$, and not on $z$. Am I right? (I don't write the statement myself, all I am doing is trying to understand it)

Comment: @Tim You are right that the statement has that property about the independence.

Comment: Added someting for the converse. Please check if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\bigvee_{x \in X} \, \bigwedge_{(y,z) \in Y \times Z} \, \bigwedge_{\epsilon > 0} \,
\bigvee_{n_\epsilon:n_\epsilon(x,y)} \, \bigwedge_{n \ge n_\epsilon}
f(x,y,z,n) \le \epsilon
$$

Looks equivalent to
$$
\bigvee_{x\in X} \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x,y,z,n) = 0 \wedge \mbox{convergence is uniform regarding } z
$$
Note: OP added $f \ge 0$.
U